# Do something in WordPress if the author is a specific person

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, author

How do I check who the author of the current post that is being viewed is? I am trying to create a custom author box, where a specific author named Vivian should have a specific a-tag when displaying her name. The rest should just have the same H3.

I have tried with `the_author` and `get_the_author_meta` display name in an IF and else statements but it doesn't seem to work. What am I missing?

```
<div class="media-body">
    <?php if (the_author('vivian')) { ?>
        <a href="https://example.com/about/"><h3>VIVIAN SOMETHING</h3></a>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <h3>A random title</h3>
    <?php } ?>
    <p><?php the_author_meta('description'); ?></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check by calling `get_the_author_meta()` with the first parameter being the author field you are comparing (display_name, first_name, nickname, etc.)

inside the loop:

```
if (get_the_author_meta('display_name') === 'vivian') {
    // do something
}
```

if outside the loop, pass in author ID

```
$author_id = get_post_field('post_author', get_queried_object_id());

if (get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id) === 'vivian') {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you, trev! I've tried replacing the if statement in my code with your solution. However, for some reason it returns else every single time. I've also tried using ID instead of display_name of that specific user I want to target but still no luck.

Comment: hmm.. do you see the author name when you run `echo get_the_author();`? This should output the `display_name` as well

Comment: also, if you're calling this code outside of the main post loop, you need to pass in the author id for `get_the_author_meta()`. I've updated my answer with an example of this.